# Xml Parsing returning null tag

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I am trying to parse a local xml file with XMLpullparser but not able to get the tag name right.

My xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   -

    <s:Header>

        <Action
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"
            s:mustUnderstand="1" >
                  http://tempuri.org/IUDTServices/ValidateUser

        </Action>
    </s:Header>
         -

    <s:Body>
 -

        <ValidateUser xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" >

            <userName>admin</userName>

            <password>admin</password>
        </ValidateUser>
    </s:Body>

</s:Envelope>
```

My activity class contains the parsing code with the entity Class as UserClass which contains the username and password parameteres.

My activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

                InputStream in_s = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open("temp.xml");
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(in_s, null);

                parseXML(parser);

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    private void parseXML(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException,IOException {

        UserClass userClass = null;

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while(eventType!= XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
            String tagName = null;
            switch(eventType){

            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:

                userClass = new UserClass();

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                tagName = parser.getName();

                if(tagName=="userName"){

                    userClass.setUsername(tagName);
                }

                if(tagName=="password"){

                    userClass.setPassword(tagName);
                }
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT:
                printValues(userClass);
                break;

            }
        }

    }

    private void printValues(UserClass userClass) {

        System.out.println(userClass.getUsername()+"   "+userClass.getPassword());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I am getting the tagName as null always..Could'nt find the reason for it.Plz help...

Comment: Use `.equals` to compare strings instead of `==`

Comment: my eventType  = parser.getEventType is returning 0..

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me..suit it according to your needs

## Edit: for parsing from iternet:

```
 URL url = new URL("http://api.discogs.com/artist/ac/dc");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
```

Dom parser

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("D:/workspace1/dd.xml");
XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
//XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//resp/artist/images/image[@uri]");
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//resp/artist/images/uri");
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int zzz = 0; zzz < nl.getLength(); zzz++)
{
    Node currentItem = nl.item(zzz);
    //String key = currentItem.getAttributes().getNamedItem("uri").getNodeValue();
    String key = currentItem.getTextContent();
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

Comment: this us using dom parse if i am right. however op is using xml pull parser. recommend XmlPullParser, which is an efficient and maintainable way to parse XML on Android http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: well thanx for telling me that, i will keep that in mind...do you know how i can use the above(my code) to parse info from url?should the above code do?(i have edited the code)

Comment: if you have a doubt ask a new question

Comment: why can't you reply here?

Comment: by the way here is the question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18384326/unable-to-fetch-xml-info-from-server

Comment: why should i? if its not relevant to the post. also if you doubt is the same as ops wait for someone to give a answer here. new doubt ask a new question

Comment: i have posted the link in the comment above

Comment: yes,when i am trying to parse the file from internet its not working

Comment: @user1901079 did u try using `.equals` ?